# How to keep display always off during the call on HTC Sense 4.1 (Android 4.0.1)?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, calls, screen, htc-sense, proximity-sensor

My wife has a problem with HTC Desire X (HTC Sense on Android 4.1) that during the call sometimes (in ~10% cases) the screens goes on for no reason. This cause phone calls to be canceled, loud speaker to be on, etc.
I do not know how to reproduce it, but I was on another side of the line already many times when this problem has happened.

The solution I see is to disable this "automatic on" feature. When the call button is pressed or the phone call is answered, the screen should go off and can be switched on **only** by pressing a hardware button (central or on/off button) and not by the proximity sensor.

I could not find an application that can do this.... Is there any?

If not, is it possible in theory to create such app without replacing the HTC Sense interface?

**ADDED:** Are there maybe some other interfaces around that have such settings? In Samsung or other devices?

Comment: I've never heard of an app to do this, and I know there isn't any option to do it with Sense. You might be able to do it with Tasker by having it detect when a call is taking place and then having it switch the screen off, but I'm not familiar enough with tasker to know for sure. But I've seen a lot of these issues are actually just a screen protector covering the proximity sensor (or a really dirty screen covering it). Does your wife have a screen protector on the phone?

Comment: No, she has no protector. But yes, the screen may become dirty or she may move the phone around or some strange problems with the sensor on this particular phone. It's difficult to tell...

Comment: I also strongly suspect some screen protector being the culprit, as it was in some related cases I've heard of. But it could also be the proximity sensor itself being faulty. I'm not sure if your device has a fitting test routine, but you could check if you find one in the service menu (`*#*#197328640#*#*` or `*#*#7378423#*#*`), otherwise check with your service technician to make sure.

Comment: I had a phone that did that before, I turned of the 'in-pocket detection' setting and it stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Is she left handed? The sensor is on the top left side of the phone making it miss the ear sometimes when holding the phone with the left hand while talking.